# Grafana, Influxdb

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I have just installed influxdb. Am trying to create a data source but it is telling me this(photo). What should I do?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tDlh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your InfluxDB is running?

It needs to be running in order to make a connection.